# CSS help to remove outline

Tags: css, woocommerce

Looking for the right css code to remove the outline around the price  $489.00 found halfway down the page http://www.korekote.com/epoxy-coating/

I hope someone can help.

Thank you,

Keith

Comment: Do u want to remove border around the 489 text?

Comment: Its coming from <p style="padding: 12px; border: 4px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);" class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline ">..</p>.. Here you need to remove the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Border is coming from inline HTML like this:

**Current HTML:**

```
<p style="padding: 12px; border: 4px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);" 
class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline ">..</p>
```

**Change it like this to remove border:**

```
<p style="padding: 12px;" class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline ">..</p>
```

**Solution 2:** **Updated**

As per your requirement changed the css like this :

```
.product.woocommerce.add_to_cart_inline {
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Right now I am using  a custom class name woo-product-price-button with my visual composer element in wordpress to control the css for the product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline:

 .woo-product-price-button, product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline, style{
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0px;
}  

But that is not working

Comment: try with !important style{ border: 0px solid #ccc !important; padding: 0px; } like this

Answer (score 2):

If you've added this button via the WooCommerce add_to_cart shortcode, you need to pass an empty style parameter, e.g.:

```
[add_to_cart id="99" style=""]
```

Otherwise, WooCommerce uses its default style, which for some reason is a 4px border.

Answer (score 0):

current HTML

```
<P class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " 
 style="BORDER-BOTTOM: #ccc 4px solid;
 BORDER-LEFT: #ccc 4px solid;
 BORDER-TOP: #ccc 4px solid;
 BORDER-RIGHT: #ccc 4px solid; 
 PADDING-BOTTOM: 12px;
 PADDING-LEFT: 12px; 
 PADDING-RIGHT: 12px; 
 PADDING-TOP: 12px" >
```

From this we need to remove all the borders i.e need to set border:none to the class `product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline`.

Comment: Right now I am using  a custom class name woo-product-price-button with my visual composer element in wordpress to control the css for the product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline:

 .woo-product-price-button, product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline, style{
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0px;
}  

But that is not working

Comment: try <P class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 12px; PADDING-LEFT: 12px; PADDING-RIGHT: 12px; PADDING-TOP: 12px;border:none" >

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Just update the tag attributes.

from :

```
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline " style="border:4px solid #ccc; padding: 12px;">
<span class="amount">$489.00</span>
<a href="http://www.korekote.com/product/kretekote/" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="6911" data-product_sku="#52000" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_variable">Select options</a>
</p>
```

to:

from :

```
<p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline ">
<span class="amount">$489.00</span>
<a href="http://www.korekote.com/product/kretekote/" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="6911" data-product_sku="#52000" data-quantity="1" class="button add_to_cart_button product_type_variable">Select options</a>
</p>
```